# How to solve an error for undefined numberofDays

Tags: java

This program is to calculate the birthdays from percentages and days. The problem is it won't compile. It says there's an error on numberofDays which is undefined. What does that mean? And how to solve it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Birthdays {
public static int DAYS_YEAR = 366;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Here are some lines that might save you a bit of time as you write your code:

    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
    int currentMonth = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the day; ");
    int currentDay = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the year: ");
    int currentYear = cin.nextInt(); 

    int numberofDayy = 7;

    int currentDays = numberofDays(currentMonth, currentDay, currentYear);
    System.out.println("Today is " + currentMonth + "/" + currentDay + "/" + currentYear + " day # " + currentDays);

    System.out.println("What is the 1st person's birth month:");
    int month1 = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the 1st person's birth day:");
    int day1 = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the 1st person's birth year:");
    int year1 = cin.nextInt();

    int birthDays = numberofDays(month1, day1, year1);
    double nextBirthday1 = birthDays - currentDays >= 0 ? birthDays - currentDays: DAYS_YEAR - (currentDays - birthDays);
    System.out.println(month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1 + ". Your next birthday is in " + nextBirthday1 + "day(s). That is " + (nextBirthday1/DAYS_YEAR) * 100 + " percent of a year away.");

    System.out.println("What is the 2nd person's birth month:");
    int month2 = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the 2nd person's birth day:");
    int day2 = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the 2nd person's birth year:");
    int year2 = cin.nextInt();

    int birthDays1 = numberofDays(month2, day2, year2);
    double nextBirthday2 = birthDays - currentDays >= 0 ? birthDays - currentDays: DAYS_YEAR - (currentDays - birthDays);
    System.out.println(month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1 + ". Your next birthday is in " + nextBirthday2 + "day(s). That is " + (nextBirthday2/DAYS_YEAR) * 100 + " percent of a year away.");


}
```

}

Comment: Can it be that there is a typo at int numberofDayy = 7; and it should be int numberofDays = 7;?

Comment: Or rather, that a method `numberofDays()` is being called, but it is not defined anywhere. At least not in the code posted. The  incorrectly named `numberofDayy` variable isn't even used either way.

Comment: Can you post the code of this method `numberofDays` ?